# Thymeleaf javascript parser breaks on double square brackets

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf 3.0.8 with Spring MVC 4 together with React, Babel and Webpack on the client side. What I want is to have Thymeleaf parse my final big .js file and put some server side variables inside and serve it to the web browser using this example here:

https://github.com/jmiguelsamper/thymeleaf3-template-modes-example

However I get this error in the browser console:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Upon inspection thymeleaf threw parseExpression on this function (not my code):

```
function removeFormattingTokens(input) {
    if (input.match(/\[[\s\S]/)) { //error here
        return input.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '');
    }
    return input.replace(/\\/g, '');
}
```

Since with thymeleaf you can use double square brackets to insert server side variables like this

```
window.myVar = [[${var}]];
```

into your javascript I'm guessing this is what's confusing the parser. Is this a bug or intended behaviour and what can it be done to overcome this issue?

I'm aware I can use `th:inline` and set some variables like that but I really wanna avoid this.

Comment: Isn't it `var code = /*[[${code}]]*/;`?

Comment: It should be, yeah, but I am encountering the same issue as Mirko just by using `[[...]]`.